# Ajuda com Header effects

Tags: javascript, css3

Olá, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer esse efeito de "gaveta" , igual está nesse site : https://warrenbrasil.com/app/#/suitability

Reparem que ele aparece com height e width 100% depois diminui pro tamanho normal de um header, eu não conheço como fazer isso apenas com CSS, acredito que possua JS junto.

Eu gostaria que não fosse um event onclick por exemplo, e fizesse automático, igual está aí

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, o ideial seria você demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esse link, pois asssim mesmo que o link fique indisponível a pergunta aida será valida. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é exatamente dessa forma que esse exemplo foi feito, mas apenas com CSS é perfeitamente possível de chegar no mesmo resultado.

Existem outras formas de fazer, mas a que eu achei mais fácil foi colocar no final do seu código uma `div` com `positon:absolute` e um `z-index` auto para garantir que não vai ficar por traz de nada, depois com a propriedade `aimation` e o `@keyframes` vc faz a animação, no caso eu fiz um animação de 1 segundo que inicia com um `delay` de 0.5 segundos e só se repete uma vez (`forwards`)

Veja como ficou o resultado:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.efeito {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    animation: anima 1s linear 500ms forwards;
}
@keyframes anima {
    to {
        top: -100vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    menu nav
</header>
<section>
    conteúdo site<br>
    <input type="text" name="" id=""><br>
    <button>button</button>
</section>

<div class="efeito">
    Texto Intro
</div>
```